# Mount inside subdir of /storage/emulated/0/

Tags: cyanogenmod, linux, storage, mount

I'm using Debian Kit to run a Linux system on my Nexus 7 running Cyanogenmod 10.1, and I'd like to be able to mount arbitrary things inside of my `/storage/emulated/0/`, such as WebDAV or sshfs. The goal is for Android apps to be able to use files provided in this way transparently.

However, whenever I try to mount anything inside of `/storage/emulated/0/`, `/sdcard/`, or `/storage/emulated/legacy/`, it doesn't appear to Android applications, but is visible from Debian. I suspect this is because these directories are themselves FUSE mounts. Things mounted from Debian to a directory outside of `/storage/emulated/0/` are visible from both Android and Debian.

Where are these directories actually located, and how can I mount something inside of them?

(Note: Debian Kit is not a chroot, but instead runs side-by-side with Android, overwriting parts of the root directory. Thus, I can directly mount to the Android filesystem without having to break out of a chroot)

Comment: I was able to untangle the knot of directories by reading the Android init scripts. /data/media/0/ is the original. By mounting sshfs (remember allow_other) to subdirectories of /data/media/0/ I have access to it from Android applications. I'd put this as an answer, but the spam-protection blocks it.

Comment: I don't know the rules of the spam-protection -- but maybe you are "too young" (fresh user) and lacked rep. With your question upvoted (and thus having a little rep), you might try again. If it fails again, and you want one of us to post the above as answer, just say so :) Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to untangle the knot of directories by reading the Android init scripts. /data/media/0/ is the original. By mounting sshfs (remember to set allow_other) to subdirectories of /data/media/0/ I have access to it from Android applications.

Comment: Mounting under /data/media/0/... worked for me too on Cyanogenmod 13 with the EasySSHFS app. Strange since it appears to be the same location as /storage/emulated/0/...